# String conversion error with DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have been struggling with this error this morning. Compiler error message:

> CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString'
>   to 'string'

is thrown at the following line of code in the view

```
<img src='@Url.Content(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.image_link))'height="42" width="42" />
```

I can't seem to display an image via a hyperlink. The hyper link is coming from SQL Server Database... I've tried sending it as a VARCHAR and a NCHAR. I have also tried To_string () as well.

Comment: `@Url.Content()` expects type of `string` as its parameter, but `Html.DisplayFor()` returns `MvcHtmlString`

Comment: Why are you using `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.image_link)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@Url.Content` method is waiting for you to pass him an object of type `string`. You are passing the result of `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.image_link)` function which is `System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString`. Ok so the source of the problem is clear.

Try using this code to fix it:

```
<img src='@Url.Content(item.image_link)'height="42" width="42" /></a>
```

I suppose that `item.image_link` is of type string and has a valid url.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, sure but will that make sense? Imagine you have DisplayTemplate for this string or attribute. What will you get is a bunch of HTML passed to `Url.Content`.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, I also can suppose you suggest exactly what I'm talking about. One could add DisplayTemplate for the entire `image_link` property to be renderred as `img` tag with appropriate `src`. But in such a case no `.ToString()` is needed.

Comment: The only logical reason that OP would have been using `DisplayFor()` in the first place is to use a `DisplayFormatSring` in a `DisplayAttribute` so assuming that is the case then `.ToString()` **is** required

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, you may happen to be right. I've asked OP about it.

Comment: I suspect in reality that OP does not actually need to use `DisplayFor()` :)

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'modelItem' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


Line 43:   <a href='@Url.Action("action", "Controller")'>
Line 44: 
Line 45:             <img src='@Url.Content(modelItem.image_link)'height="42" width="42" /></a>
Line 46:     </div>


Source File: C:\Users\Gareth\Desktop\PiranhaCMSy\PiranhaCMS\PiranhaCMS\Areas\legacyPages\Views\gallary_view\Index.cshtml    Line: 45


Still no joy on that work around.. Yeah there url is valid for sure. I can pass it by hard coding is as a test.

Comment: @Sephen Muecke I did try converting it to a alas this didn't work out ether.... Something strange is happening with it for sure.

I will keep reading up on what the deal is in the mean time.

Comment: @TuckRollworthy, try to use code after my edits. `item.image_link`